# Java using functions

Tags: java, function, class

I have some problems with using function when I call the other class.

Main class:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    baseIteration(new Function() {
        public double calculate(double x) {
            return Math.sin(x) - Math.log10(x);
        }

        @Override
        public Object apply(Object t) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }.calculate(double x),0,10.0);
}
```

And baseIteration function:

```
public static void baseIteration(Function f, double a, double b) {
    double prev = f.calculate(a);
    double step = (b-a)/10;
    for(double p = a+step; p<=b+10e-8; p+=step) {
        double curr = f.calculate(p);
    }
}
```

It is not all, but main problem: f.calculation is undefined!

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Function` does not have the `calculate` method, it only has the `apply` method. And you normally don't need to implement `Function` explicitly.

Try the following:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    baseIteration(x -> Math.sin(x) - Math.log10(x), 0, 10.0);
}

public static void baseIteration(Function<Double, Double> f, double a, double b) {
    double prev = f.apply(a);
    double step = (b-a)/10;
    for(double p = a+step; p<=b+10e-8; p+=step) {
        double curr = f.apply(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is started working! Thank's you so much! I have problems with algorithm now, but, it is started working! Thanks!